# How to make html elements scale correctly, when dealing with long text

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Long text **without spaces** makes html elements like div scale width in very unexpected way.

For example:

```
<div className='Test'>
        <div className='one'>
            11111
        </div>
        <div className='two'>
            22222222 222222222
        </div>
        <div className='three'>
            33333333333333333333333333333333333333333333333
        </div>
</div>


.one {
  width: 20px;
  border: solid green;
}

.two {
  border: solid purple;
}

.three {
  border: solid blue;
}

.Test {
  border: solid black;
}
```

Why this is happening and how we can fix it?
By the way I meant mobile auto scaling, because desktop browsers do not scale width on it's own.

Comment: Use display flex and then flex-wrap,  may need to add a max-width as well.

Comment: @SabirHossain Not related to my question. I asked for long undividable words, so wrap will make no difference.

Comment: What do you mean by scale?

Comment: Maybe I used a wrong word, sorry. I meant how to make html elements adapt theirs width to match screen width.

Comment: You can cut it by overflow:hidden, that is maybe not what you want. Or scrollable by overflow: auto. Fitting the text by font-size just with javascript.

Comment: @kmgt Mobile browsers already scales width correctly, the problem is only with its containers.